# powershell script for finding the total memory space of c drive

Tags: powershell

I want a PowerShell script to get the total memory space of C drive and used memory space in GB, if the total space is less than 200 GB it should print disk space is less than 200.

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
$task=gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
if($task.Size -lt 200)
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is less than 200."
}
else
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is greater than 200."
}
```

I am getting all drive space on the above code, I need only C drive information and if condition is not working properly,Some one help me through this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Get-Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=win10-ps) cmdlet -

```
if (((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).Size)/1GB -lt 200)
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is less than 200."
}
else
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is greater than 200."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to run this test on win7 - even with ps5.1 - you can't use the `Get-Volume` cmdlet. [*sigh ...*] so here is one that uses CMI/WMI for that.

what it does ...

- sets a min free space threshold
- uses the faster, non-deprecated CIM stuff to get the info on drive C:
- only returns info if the C: drive meets the min freespace requirement
- uses `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()` to see if the result has any info in it
- then uses an IF structure to decide what message to show
- if space is too low, it uses the `Write-Warning` cmdlet for the nice orange text [*grin*]

here's the code ...

```
$MinFreeSpace_GB = 800

$CDriveMinFree = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {
        $_.DeviceID -eq 'C:' -and
        $_.FreeSpace -lt $MinFreeSpace_GB * 1GB
        }))

if ($CDriveMinFree)
    {
    'The C: drive has at least {0} GB free.' -f $MinFreeSpace_GB
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Warning ('Low free space on Drive C:!')
    }
```

output on my 600 GB free C: drive with the test threshold set to 800 ...

```
WARNING: Low free space on Drive C:!
```